# Google Map Static API with dynamic markers via Google Charts API

Tags: google-visualization, google-maps-static-api

I want to show static map with dynamic markers.
So i'm using Google Maps Static API with icon made of Google Charts API.

All marker icon urls are incoded in right way (%257C instead "|" etc).

My code:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Moscow&zoom=10&size=600x450&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C9%257CFFFFFF|55.7959364,37.7052089&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C14%257CFFFFFF|55.8452904,37.3614846&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C15%257CFFFFFF|55.712056,37.732715&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C16%257CFFFFFF|55.689701,37.574149&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C21%257CFFFFFF|55.6491446,37.7421431&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C33%257CFFFFFF|55.748237,37.816418&markers=icon:|55.7781055,37.5472178
```

As you seen, there are 7 markers, but only 5 of them shows correctly.

But, if we get 7 maps separately with only 1 markers - everything is ok.
Like this:

```
   https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Moscow&zoom=10&size=600x450&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C9%257CFFFFFF|55.7959364,37.7052089
```

Or if we replace dynamic text value in markers to something identiсal like '012345' - everything is ok too. Like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Moscow&zoom=10&size=600x450&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C012345%257CFFFFFF|55.7959364,37.7052089&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C012345%257CFFFFFF|55.8452904,37.3614846&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C012345%257CFFFFFF|55.712056,37.732715&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C012345%257CFFFFFF|55.689701,37.574149&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C012345%257CFFFFFF|55.6491446,37.7421431&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C012345%257CFFFFFF|55.748237,37.816418&markers=icon:http://chart.apis.google.com/chart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_text_small%26chld%3DbbT%257C012345%257CFFFFFF|55.7781055,37.5472178
```

URL max size is 2048, mine examaple is shorter. 
So, I have no idea how to show all of my markers in one static map.

Comment: Find the answer: **Static Maps service allows up to five unique custom icons per request. 
Note that each of these unique icons may be used multiple times within the static map.**

Comment: See also: Issue 7575: Feature request: More than 5 custom icons https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7575